# Should an uncoupling membrane be installed on concrete floor before tiling in a high rise building in hot climate?

Tags: concrete, flooring, tile

I want to renovate my new apartment. It is in a 30 year old high rise building with concrete floor in Bangkok. The temperature all year around is about 20 to 40 degrees Celsius.

I saw many renovation videos and it seems the experts (mostly from America or Europe) all recommend using uncoupling membranes. I think I understand how these uncoupling membranes work.

It seems here in Bangkok uncoupling membranes are more or less unknown and "nobody" is using them. The reason might be that craftsmanship in general is not very sophisticated here. But it also might be possible that with the conditions here, especially not much temperature change, it is not necessary to use uncoupling membranes.

Should uncoupling membranes be used under the described conditions? Thanks.

Comment: What, in your view, is the point of an “uncoupling” membrane as it relates to temperature and humidity? How is it different from standard practices for conditioned space and maintaining temperature and humidity at a constant level?

Comment: They're not just for temperature, also soundproofing, to avoid the neighbor below hearing every step you make.

Comment: @RibaldEddie: I am not sure if I understand your question. In many countries the temperature varies from below freezing to > 30 degrees Celsius. There is a lot more to contract and expand compared to a climate when temperatures don't change so much.